# C# - SQL - add rowsCount dynamically to data models

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dapper

I have a code where i do sql query by casting the table model like this:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}...", tableName...);
```

and then:

```
IEnumerable<T> r = dbConn.Connection.Query<T>(sql...);
```

the thing is if i want to get total rowsCount(of course i can get count on the "r" but if there is a where clause its not possible because i want total count) i have to another query without where.
so i want to remove the second query. i did this in sql query to get rowsCount:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT *, count(*) over() rowsCount FROM {0}...", tableName...);
```

i can get the rowsCount with this query but since neither one of models has rowsCount i cant access it, is there any suggestions on how i should do it?

Edit:
first query has paging filter by using offset and limit, so i want totalcount not the count of filtered query.
I'm looking to see if there is a way to not use two seperate queries, and get results and also rowsCount by just one query.

Comment: Why not keep a count as you enumerate it? Why is the count important? What do you use it for? Why don't you just ToArray() your IEnumerable and use the length?

Comment: As i said i want totalCount not count of paged query, there is a paging filter by using offset and limit

Comment: @CaiusJard lets say i want to use it for paging and calculating total results so i can show page numbers based on that result

Comment: Do it as a subquery without where but with count and then outer query with where?

Comment: yeah i already have that, and its working but it makes two seperate queries so i wanna remove second query to reduce pressure on sql server

Comment: You need two queries. There is no easy way around that. PetaPoco (and I suspect other micro ORMs like Dapper) has ways to get the data and the overall count - but behind the scenes it is running two queries.

Comment: I'm not sure you can unless you want to add in some simple retrieving a table count estim.. and that goes out of the window when you get more complex with your query. I always felt that paging was a relatively useless device, tbh - saying to a user "your query returned a million companies so we broke them up into 10,000 pages of 100 records. Have a wild guess at where the data you want is" isn't really improving their chances of finding what they want .. Better search is better (when was the last time you went past page 3 of google?) so the user can find what they want in the first 100 hits..

Comment: @CaiusJard well yeah you're right about paging but in shopping websites its kinda important to show user result of filter, so having it is a must...

Comment: @mjwills i'v done a lot of research and ways to remove second query because it creates overhead on server, I'v thought about reflecting generic type into a type which has rowsCount in its model, idk im just guessing...

Comment: Reflection / generics is completely irrelevant (I mean it can be helpful in terms of the C# side of things, but it won't magically give you the count) - the database needs to tell you the count, so you need to ask for it.

Comment: As i mentioned with the second sql query which i wrote, i have totalCount but since dapper maps rows based on the model it is cast on, rowsCount is not accessible, thats why i suggested if somehow i be able to add rowsCount dynamically to the model, problem will be solved...

Comment: If by "dynamically" you mean "after running a second query", then sure. Check PetaPoco for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do 2 SQL queries.

Nothing stopping you running them in one SQL block or calling a stored proc with output parameters. So you don't have to make 2 calls but you will need 2 queries at least.

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/stored-procedure-output-parameters/

If you are worried about performance of a total count just make sure you have an index on the smallest column in that table and it should be mega fast.

The below example return a dataset and an output in one call

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.DataSetAndOutput
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DataSetAndOutput
    @YourId BIGINT, 
    @CountRecords INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN 

    SELECT * FROM YourTable
    WHERE Id = @YourId

    SET @CountRecords = (SELECT COUNT(YourId) FROM YourTable)

END
GO

-- Test the output
DECLARE @ResultCount INT
EXEC dbo.DataSetAndOutput @YourId= 252452, @CountRecords = @ResultCount OUTPUT

SELECT @ResultCount AS TheCount
```

[image]